# Background scripts loaded multiple times

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have 2 background pages declared in my extension manifest and the extension itself is persistent:
"background": {
        "persistent": true,
        "scripts": [ "UrlMonitor.js", "background.js" ]
    }

In my background.js, I am creating an instance of the UrlMonitor (declated in UrlMonitor.js)

```
var monitor = new UrlMonitor();
```

In UrlMonitor.js, I have a few global variables accessed by the event callbacks.

```
var nativePort = null;
var TabInfoKP = new Object();
var TabInfoKPN = new Object();
```

I have noticed that the call the script is loaded multiple times, with multiple calls to

```
var monitor = new UrlMonitor();
```

and

```
var nativePort = null;
var TabInfoKP = new Object();
var TabInfoKPN = new Object();
```

I was expecting the scripts to be loaded once and remain in the background, responding only to event callbacks. I am using the globals TabInfoKP to track tab status (by updating them in the event callbacks). With multiple initializations, I loose the previously stored info in the variables. The load happens even when a new tab is created/updated etc.

Am I doing something wrong or is this expected functionality?
If this is expected functionality, what are my alternatives?

P.S, I am totally new to JS and chrome extensions.

Comment: Impossible to say without more of your code. But no, the background script should execute only once if it's persistent.

Comment: The only code missing is the callback. I have callbacks for  tabs.OnCreated and tabs.OnUpdated and all they do is add the tabId and the url being accessed into the global TabInfoKP variable.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... I have managed to avoid this from happening. 
I have been running this script under the debugger and every time I hit the breakpoint, after debugging, I press F5 (old habit from Visual Studio) and that seems to trigger the issue. Maybe the runtime is reloading the script and starting all over again.

Sorry about the trouble, but this has been troubling me all day today and all I had to do was hover over the continue icon on the chrome debugger to realize F5 wasn't the assigned shortcut key!
Does anyone know what's the shortcut to continue in the chrome debugger?

Comment: it's f8 while on the sources tab